# How to resolve Cannot find module 'angularfire2' when using Angular-CLI and RC.4 with AngularFire 2 and Firebase 3

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm using angular-cli with the lastest RC4 version of Angular.

I was following the steps [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md).

But I had to make a few very small changes. For one, I'm installing AngularFire this way:
    `npm install git+https://github.com/angular/angularfire2.git --save` so that I have a version that is compatible with RC4.

Secondly, when doing the typings step I do this:
    `typings install file:node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts --save --global && typings install` because that's where the firebase.d.ts file is now it seems.

Next I do this:

```
var map = {
    'firebase': 'vendor/firebase/firebase.js',
    'angularfire2': 'vendor/angularfire2'
};

/** User packages configuration. */

var packages = {
    angularfire2: {
        defaultExtension: 'ts',
        main: 'angularfire2.ts'
    }
};
```

Where I use the .ts file because there isn't a .js file for angularfire2 in the node_modules/angularfire2 folder. Even in the source folder it's just .ts files.

So, once I get to step 7, and do this:

```
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase } from 'angularfire2';
```

everything falls apart. I'm not sure why, it should work?

[here's the project on github](https://github.com/thehashrocket/angular-analytics)

UPDATE:

So, I tried changing the extension from .ts to .js in `system-config.ts`.

Then, I tried the following:

```
➜ Projects rm -rf angular-analytics 
➜ Projects npm uninstall -g angular-cli
➜ Projects npm cache clean
➜ Projects npm install -g angular-cli@latest
➜ Projects git clone git@github.com:thehashrocket/angular-analytics.git
➜ Projects cd angular-analytics 
➜ angular-analytics git:(master) npm install
➜ angular-analytics git:(master) ng build
```

However, the result was this (again):

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-89eNuVcv.tmp/0/src/main.ts (4, 53): Cannot find module 'angularfire2'.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:120:19)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
    at /Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.Plugin (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:10:31)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.CachingWriter [as constructor] (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:21:10)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:26:49)
    at Angular2App._getTsTree (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:331:18)
    at Angular2App._buildTree (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:124:23)
    at new Angular2App (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:53:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/angular-cli-build.js:10:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:15:19)
    at /Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/commands/build.js:32:24
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at /Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:331:11
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/angular-analytics/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

Am I just being really dumb and missing a step? I feel like I am . . . It's going to be something obvious that I either didn't know about, or completely overlooked. :(

Comment: Which version of angular-cli? Beta.10? Or master? You don't need to use AngularFire2 from master for it to work with RC.4. You can ignore the npm warnings. If npm won't let you proceed, the update to npm 3.10.5.

Comment: What version of typings is installed globally and locally? Try wiping your typings, tmp, dist, and node_modules dirs after getting typings 1.3.x installed locally and globally.

Comment: @Splaktar i'm using the following:
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
node: 5.10.1
os: darwin x64
npm: 3.10.5
typings: 1.3.2

Comment: your repo link is a 404 for me.

Comment: Can you try using "angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.2"? It works fine with Angular 2 RC.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typings should look like this for firebase:

```
"dependencies": {
  "es6-promise": "github:typed-typings/npm-es6-promise#fb04188767acfec1defd054fc8024fafa5cd4de7",
  "firebase": "github:typed-typings/npm-firebase"
},
```

Your `package.json` should have this for AngularFire2. It works fine with Angular 2 RC.4:

`"angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.2",`

Using `npm install -g npm` should get you npm version `3.10.5` which will not fail due to the peer dependencies not being Angular 2 RC.2.

It looks like your repo is private since the link is a 404. So I can't really test this out or see the exact problem you are having, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete firebase and angularefire2 folders from node_modules
2. In Package.json change your angularfire2  and firebase  dependencies to look like this:

   [Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AYq3.png)
3. npm install
4. ng serve

An easier solution is to change import statement to import the deprecated module, so instead of:

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

Use this:

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

This will solve the subscribe error, without changing package.json or deleting anything.